# Windows SBS 2008 not sending alert emails

Tags: windows, email, windows-sbs-2008

We have a SBS 2008 system and Backup Exec doing a hard disk backup each night.

For some reason the emails from Backup Exec on the server are not being received in our inboxes.

We are using Exchange 2007 and SMTP.

Is this some kind of Microsoft Security setting we need to enable?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming it's never worked, you're probably not doing authenticated SMTP from Backup Exec and, as such, Exchange's default receive connector isn't accepting the messages.

I don't recall if Backup Exec permits you to enter credentials for SMTP servers or not. If it does, enter valid credentials there and all should be well.

If it doesn't, have a look at [this entry from the Exchange team blog post](http://msexchangeteam.com/archive/2006/12/28/432013.aspx) re: configuring a receive connector that will allow anonymous relaying.